# Linq to SQL Repository Pattern and string ID

Tags: linq-to-sql

Hi I am trying to use a Repository Pattern with Linq To Sql

I am using some of the code from here(http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/03/using-irepository-pattern-with-linq-to.html)

T GetById(int id); is the repository method, I am interested in.

Inside the codebase, it converts the int id passed to lambda expression(p => p.Id == Id)
it only deals with Int Id's and throws an exception for everything
else.

For tables that have string Id, do I create an overload in my repository like
T GetById(string id) and than create the lambda expression like mike is doing for int Types?

Answer (score 0):

i tried the overload method and it worked. should have tried, before posting.
any comments/suggestions are WELCOME